# How to remove cursor from background text field

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a task that display cafes around a location by using zipcode.
If we enter zipcode in a text field.it will get all cafes and display in a alert box.

Problem is if we enter zipcode and press enter cursor is presenting in background text field and if we enter any thing it is typed in that text field.

Comment: Please add the code, so that we can check whats going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to remove the focus which is set to text box.
For that, you can have jquery `blur()` method.

To disable auto-focus on a particular element, pass the element id as below,

```
$(function(){
    $('#someid').blur();
});
```